# Which Payment Processor should we use?

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, iats

We are using Civi 5.0.1 on Wordpress 4.9.1

Recently I asked if anyone is using Payflow as your payment processor.  Not a single person could answer.  So I don't believe anyone is using Payflow on their civi install.    Also after a lot of troubleshooting, I have come to the conclusion that Payflow is no longer compatible with Civi.

OUr organization needs a reliable payment processor that can process credit cards and recurring payments.  We are a U.S. based non-profit.   Can anyone tell me what is the most popular processor to use with Civi?  I looked into IATS Payments.  Are they a reliable options?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There likely isn't one clear winner here.

But authorize.net has been my go-to recently. That and PayPal Pro are built-in to Civi out of the box.

The Stripe payment processor extension is operating on 855 installs. iATS Payments is on 602 installs.

Here is a very helpful review from Gingko Street Labs which also addresses the 4 aforementioned processors: https://ginkgostreet.com/content/evaluating-payment-processor-options.

I'm on WP as well.

Comment: Thank you.  That link is very helpful.    I know all of those options are build in with Civi, but working with Paypal Payments Pro and Payflow works finewith one time transactions, but will  not work at all with Recurring.  We do have recurring enabled on the merchant account.  After a lot of digging and testing, we have come to conclusion that Paypal has  made some changes, and Civi needs to be updated to be compatible with those changes.  After 4 months of wrestling with this, we decided it is time to try to different processor.

Comment: Interesting. I was hesitant to mention PayPal Pro because the last time I tried to integrate it was way back in 2014 it also had the same issue with recurring and perhaps another issue I cannot recall now. But I didn't want to throw it under the bus right away as I thought that may have been resolved.

Comment: I am glad it is not just us who was wrestling with that.  I am learning towards IATS at this point.

Answer (score 3):

The key to selecting a Payment Processor is the functionality you’re looking for.

The iATS extension is probably the single-most sophisticated payment-processing integration (for US/CA) - especially re: recurring contribution functionality and the abilty to control/edit/update/schedule recurring contributions from the CiviCRM side.

And finally please note that the iATS Payments Extension now also ships with CiviCRM Core.

Answer (score 2):

We use Stripe Extension (com.drastikbydesign.stripe), which is very easy to implement (to open an account, you just have to provide de Bank IBAN)

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the answers given and want to emphasize to the choice of payment processor is context dependent.

It does not only depend on the given functionality but also on the costs.

Some charge a fee per transaction, some a monthly fee, some a combination. So the total cost for a payment processor could differ from organisation to organisation.

So it is a decission you have to make. And implementing a payment processor is not difficult (from a developers perspective) so if you found a payment processor you can probably aslo find a developer to implement it in CiviCRM.

ps. the Omnipay extension contains quite a bit of payment processor implementations: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor